# cross tables query

Tags: sql, oracle

Let us say we have 2 tables :  A and B.

In table A we have payments for customers. 12 payments each year for each customer identified by numClient column and the amount of payment identified by payment column.

In table B there is the sum of payments of the year for every customer so just one row each year per customer still identified by a numClient column and payment identified by yearPayment column.

I would like a query that lists all customers (displaying numClient) whose yearPayment of table B is different from the sum of his payments in table A.

As those tables cover differents years, I would like to query only for 2018. In table A, the payment date is PaymentDate Column. In table B, the year of payment is YearPayment column.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data that covers all the scenarios you're interested in for both tables, along with the output you're expecting from that data.

Comment: You don't need table B, as all data u need is already in table A

Comment: Nature gave us Materialized Views and Query Rewrite expressly to avoid this sort of problem. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/qrbasic.htm#DWHSG-GUID-DB76286B-8557-446B-A6CC-BC987C378076)

Answer (score 3):

The whole story sounds *wrong*. Not your words, but the model - why are you using table B? Keep payments where they are (table A). If you have to sum them, do so. Or create a view. But, keeping them separately in two tables just asks for a problem (the one you have now - finding a difference).

Anyway:

```
select a.id_customer, sum(a.payment), b.sum_payment
from a join b on a.id_customer = b.id_customer
where extract(year from a.date_column) = 2018
  and extract(year from b.date_column) = 2018
group by a.id_customer, b.sum_payment
having b.sum_payment <> sum(a.payment)
```